# ¿Cómo unir dos o más objetos y ordenarlos en un arreglo en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, firebase, union

Tengo objetos que salen de una base de datos (firebase). Lo que estoy haciendo es traerme todos los documentos (registros) de la base de datos en donde el **propietario.identificador** sea = al id del usuario autenticado, de esta manera:

```
const obtenerCursos = async () => {
const q = query(
collection(firebase.db, "misCursos"),
where("propietario.identificador", "==", id)
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Esto me devuelve dos objetos por separados:
[image: Objetos del identificador]

**doc.data()** es el que devolvió eso por separado. Aquí los objetos:

```
// Objeto 1
{
"0":
{
"modulos": [{"video1":"https"}],
"categoria":"ventas",
"detalle_curso": "DETALLE CURSO AQUI",
"nombre": "Vender Online",
"cantidad_modulos":5,
"id":3, 
"propietario":{"identificador":"rIZsl1Ple8bWYOe0HkDLJWc0Udj2","nombrePropietario":"Jorge"}
}

// Objeto 2
{
"0":
{
"id":4,
"cantidad_modulos":6,
"detalle_curso":"DETALLE CURSO POTENCIA TU NEGOCIO AQUI",
"nombre":"Potencia tu negocio",
"modulos":[{"video1":"https"}]
}

"1":
{
"nombre":"Trading Avanzado",
"cantidad_modulos":10,
"id":2,
"categoria":"trading",
"modulos":[{"video1":"https"}]
}

"2":
{
"cantidad_modulos":5,
"categoria":"trading",
"modulos":[{"video1":"https"}],
"precio":100,
"nombre":"Trading Básico",
"id":1
},
"propietario":{"nombrePropietario":"Jorge","identificador":"rIZsl1Ple8bWYOe0HkDLJWc0Udj2"}}
```

Lo que quiero lograr es unir en un arreglo esos objetos y que cada posición del arreglo sea 1 objeto sin el elemento "propietario".
En este caso quedaría algo así sin importar el orden de los objetos:

```
arrayX = [

// posición 0
  {
  id: 3,
  nombre: "Vender Online",
  categoria: "ventas",
  precio: "100"
  },
  //posición 1
  {
  id: 1,
  nombre: "Programación",
  categoria: "informatica",
  precio: "100"
  },
//posición 2
  {
  id: 2,
  nombre: "Trading Avanzado",
  categoria: "trading",
  precio: "150"
  },
//posición 3
  {
  id: 4,
  nombre: "Trading Básico",
  categoria: "trading",
  precio: "100"
  }

]
```

Probé creando un objeto vacío y aplicando push al objeto = doc.data() dentro del ciclo foreach pero me devuelve los valores dentro de otro array.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo, espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Por favor comparte los objetos recibidos como texto y no como una imágen. Puedes hacer `JSON.stringify(obj)` para que se vea mejor.

Comment: Listo, actualizado.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "0": {
      "modulos": [
        {
          "video1": "https"
        }
      ],
      "categoria": "ventas",
      "detalle_curso": "DETALLE CURSO AQUI",
      "nombre": "Vender Online",
      "cantidad_modulos": 5,
      "id": 3,
      "propietario": {
        "identificador": "rIZsl1Ple8bWYOe0HkDLJWc0Udj2",
        "nombrePropietario": "Jorge"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "0": {
      "id": 4,
      "cantidad_modulos": 6,
      "detalle_curso": "DETALLE CURSO POTENCIA TU NEGOCIO AQUI",
      "nombre": "Potencia tu negocio",
      "modulos": [
        {
          "video1": "https"
        }
      ]
    },
    "1": {
      "nombre": "Trading Avanzado",
      "cantidad_modulos": 10,
      "id": 2,
      "categoria": "trading",
      "modulos": [
        {
          "video1": "https"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2": {
      "cantidad_modulos": 5,
      "categoria": "trading",
      "modulos": [
        {
          "video1": "https"
        }
      ],
      "precio": 100,
      "nombre": "Trading Básico",
      "id": 1,
      "propietario": {
        "nombrePropietario": "Jorge",
        "identificador": "rIZsl1Ple8bWYOe0HkDLJWc0Udj2"
      }
    }
  }
]


const obtenerCursos = async () => {
  const resultadoFinal = []
  data.forEach(doc => {
    let arrayData = Object.values(doc)
    arrayData.map(element => {
      if(element.propietario){
       delete element.propietario
      }
      resultadoFinal.push(element);
    })
  });
  console.log(resultadoFinal)   
}

obtenerCursos()
```

Comment: Eso es lo que había intentado hacer pero eso me devolvería un arreglo de tamaño = 2, en la posición 0 los 3 objetos, y en la posición 1, 1 objeto. Y yo quiero obtener un sólo arreglo en donde estén los 4 objetos (arreglo de tamaño 4). En donde la posición 0 es un objeto, posición 1 otro y así sucesivamente...

Comment: a ver si entendi, modifique la respuesta, saque el fetch y puse data hardcodeada, no explique nada porque no se si es eso lo que buscas